# Installing Geddy with npm

Tags: node.js, geddy

When I try to install Geddy using npm I get the following errors:

http://s15.postimage.org/rwkrcxeuz/geddy.png

I've installed the SDK and the VS 2008, but still installing Geddy gives the errors... The Geddy commands are working, for now, but I might encouter some problems later because of the errors.

Any suggestions about getting rid of the errors?

Comment: `node-gyp` lists a requirement of [Visual Studio C++ **2010**](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#installation). VS 2008 might still work sometimes, but it's not actively supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try the options given [here](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues/182)

1. Install Microsoft Windows SDK for your Windows version, .NET Framework 3, Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
2. Set environment variable PATH to include directories required
3. Try installing it with Administrator rights